# use a dataframe column for the color of a graph line with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I draw a graph like this:

```
p1=ax1.plot(df['timestamp'], df['break_even'], color='blue', zorder = 0)
```

but I would like the line to change color based on another column:

```
p1=ax1.plot(df['timestamp'], df['break_even'], color=df['trade_color'], zorder = 0)
```

this will not work, I get:

```
ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 0           red
1         green
2           red
3           red
4         green
          ...
```

how can this be achieved?

this is an example to test:

```
data = [[1, 10, 'red'], [2, 15, 'green'], [3, 14, 'blue']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['x', 'y', 'color'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df['x'], df['y'], color='darkorange', zorder = 0)
```

this will work, but:

```
ax.plot(df['x'], df['y'], color=df['color'], zorder = 0)
```

will not. How can I get each line segment to use the color I need? (I have just 2 colors if it makes a difference)

Comment: @anky, I added a example that can run

Answer (score 0):

Just plot part of the dataframe each time with the color you want:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[1, 10, 'red'], [2, 15, 'green'], [3, 14, 'blue']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['x', 'y', 'color'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i in df.index:
    '''
    Get two rows each time, every row has a point (x, y)
    Two points can draw a line, use the color defined by first row
    '''
    partial = df.iloc[i:i+2, :]
    ax.plot(partial['x'], partial['y'], color=partial['color'].iloc[0], zorder = 0)

plt.show()
```

[image]